# Change javafx scene from different class

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have a maze game where a player is moving through a maze trying to make it to the end and when the player makes it to the window with the game gets replaced with a victory screen that says "winner" and has a "quit" button but I'm struggling with making the scene of the stage change.

this is the relevant code of the ending tile:

```
public class EndTile extends MazeRoute{

    public void MoveHere(Player Player){
    Player.setXpos(getTileXpos());
    Player.setYpos(getTileYpos());

    MazeGame.primaryStage.setScene(MazeGame.winnerScene);
```

and this is the relevant part of the primary stage of my game

```
public class MazeGame extends Application {
    public static GridPane winnerLayout = new GridPane();
    public static Stage primaryStage;
    public static Scene winnerScene = new Scene(winnerLayout);


    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        try{
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.BLACK);

            Text winnerText = new Text("you win!");
            winnerLayout.getChildren().add(winnerText);

            primaryStage.setTitle("MazeGame");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
```

Basically I am asking how I change the scene in my `primaryStage` using the `moveHere` method in `EndTile`.

What I'm using right now gives me a `NullPointerException` when making it to the end tile.

Edit: added `MazeGame.primaryStage = primaryStage;` to my start method as @fabian suggested in the comments and this fixed the problem.

Comment: You never assign the `MazeGame.primaryStage` field. If you want to keep using `static` fields to pass the data, you need to do `MazeGame.primaryStage = primaryStage;` in the `start` method.

Comment: Typically in games you have some main game loop.(Controller) where the logic is. You should check for win condition there . OR if event driven. there should still be some Controller registered as a listener maybe on that tile for a win event.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.